# how to show toast message bt the name of my tab titles stored is array on swipe or tab touched

Tags: android, toast

> how to show toast message for tab tiles, public String[] tab_titles = {"Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"}; when on the individual tab

Comment: http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: i need for tab titles, when i clicled on sun on my tab , its should show sun as toast message.

Comment: Toast.makeText(context, "your tab title e.g getTabTitle", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: public String[] tab_titles = {"Sun","Mon","Tues","Wed","Thurs","Fri","Sat"};
  for (String tabHeader : tab_titles) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tabHeader).setTabListener(MyActivity.this));

Comment: @Override
    public void onTabSelected(android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), tab.getText() + " Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 but this code shows " tues" with "sun", ie current day with the item on the first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that you can get tab name.but you may get TabSpec name.
try below code hope it will help you.

```
  TabHost tabHost;
  tabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tab_host);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tabspec1").setIndicator("Academics").setContent(R.id.academicslistview));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("Tabspec2").setIndicator("Extracurricular").setContent(R.id.extracurricularlistview));
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int selectedTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
            Log.d("Tab", "count" + selectedTab);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tab Title" + mTabHost.getCurrentTab(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```